# Select level 1 children elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML structure

```
<div id="el">
  ...
  <div>
    ... 
    <div class="x"> 
      ...
      <div>
        <div class="x"> 
         ...
        </div> 
      </div>
      ...
    </div>  
    ...
  </div>


</div>
```

How can I select `.x` trough `#el` but only if it's on the first level?

`#el > .x` it won't work because .x can have other parent elements :s

If it's not possible, how could I ignore .x elements that have parents with a certain class ?

Comment: The phrasing is tripping me up. You want to use #el to select .x. However, it should only select .x if it is the direct descendent of #el. Any more deeply nested and you don't want it selected. Is that correct? In other words, in your sample, NO divs with class 'x' should be selected, because none of them are the direct descendent of #el?

Comment: @GregPettit: I don't think that's what is meant, because if so, then the `#el > .x` would work fine because it would return no elements. But you're right, there certainly are some ambiguities in the wording.

Comment: You got it. The first line implies `#el > .x` would work. The second line says "that doesn't work". There's a contradiction; and whether or not `.x` CAN have other parent elements seems irrelevant. I just don't understand what needs selecting.

Comment: @GregPettit: Yeah my interpretation of the first level that has `.x` could be off the mark too. Could be any `.x` that doesn't have another `.x` between it and `#el`. Maybe @Alex will give some insight.

Comment: I want only the first .x descendant to be selected, and ignore .x descendants of .x

Comment: @Alex: I'm curious to know why you accepted an answer that selects the elements you said you want it to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use the children() command for jQuery as it only travels down 1 level.

$("#el div").children(".x")

This would select it properly.

http://api.jquery.com/children/

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .children() method allows us to search through the immediate children
>   of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object
>   from the matching elements. The .find() and .children() methods are
>   similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the
>   DOM tree. Note also that like most jQuery methods, .children() does
>   not return text nodes; to get all children including text and comment
>   nodes, use .contents().
>
> The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type
>   that we can pass to the $() function. If the selector is supplied, the
>   elements will be filtered by testing whether they match it.

Comment: This won't work because #el has no children with the class '.x'. You could get the same result as @jessegavin by adding an extra void `.children()` inline.

Comment: So you could still do $("#el div").children(".x") and it would work fine. Hardly feel like it was worth a minus 1 ;)

Comment: I didn't minus it. That said, a minus usually means "this is wrong" which it was until the edit. If you don't want less generous people than myself to me to minus it, test it before replying. ;-)

Comment: I gave the -1 because the question clearly states that selecting direct children won't necessarily work. Doing `$("#el div").children(".x")` isn't any better.

Comment: ...since it will select all the `.x` elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can do two selectors. One for get, and another for negate...

```
$('#el .x').not('#el .x .x');
```

It can be work.
Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/hPsY2/

Comment: This won't work if an ancestor of `#el` happens to have the `x` class. You'd need to include `#el` in the second selector.

Comment: Brilliant. This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function which loops through all the `.x` elements inside of `#el` and returns those `.x` elements which do not have an ancestor with class of `x`.

**Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6AwcX/**

```
function getTopLevelXElements() {
    var xElements = [];
    $("#el .x").each(function(i, el) {
        if ($(el).parent().closest(".x").length == 0)
          xElements.push(el);
    });
    return $(xElements);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that that number of parent elements .x can have is variable... so I can't do that:(

Comment: then you can just use `.el .x`... all `.x` in `.el` will be selected

Comment: just do a not, after... like `.not(".x .x")`

Comment: @GregPettit: Seems clear in the question that the type and number of the ancestors of the targeted `x` element is not known. This answer is specific to the exact code example.

Comment: Our definitions of "clear" must vary. But you've forced me to re-read and actually the original post is clearer than your explanation. ;-) Deleting the original comment.